# Design Pattern for angular2 + big model + external service mapping

Tags: angular, design-patterns, model

I have a third party service with a lot of fields. Every field has an id and many times the values do too. I need to bind those to a model which I use in an angular4+ application.

I thought on using enums to map the external service Ids to names, to get the ids readable on JavaScript side. Is there a better way to do this? One that involves less coupling to the third party service?